# Retrigger build chain and pick up changed source

Tags: teamcity

I have three build configurations inside a build. Let's say A, B and C. C depends on B and B depends on A.

Suppose I trigger a build manually on C. Now, A, B, C steps will get queued for build.

Step A might cause a source update and commit to source control. When this happens, I want to stop the entire build chain first. Then I want to Retrigger (automatically) C with the same parameters as when it was run manually in the first place - but using the new source.

Is there any way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can absolutely do this with native functionality in 3 steps.

1. Force Failure (for A)
2. Configure "Fail when dependency fails" (for B and C)
3. "Retrigger on failure" (C).

---

### Step 1

You can make a build fail manually by setting the build status. There is a post on this in the [jetbrains support issues](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206297579-Force-build-to-fail):

> To fail build it should be enough to print something like this:
>
> "##teamcity[buildStatus status='FAILURE']"

For the sake of maintainability, I recommend doing this in an extra command line build step.

### Step 2

You can trigger canceling a build when a dependency fails. This can chain transitively. For your project B and C, set the following in the snapshot dependency:
[image]

### Step 3

There is a build trigger called "Retry Build Trigger" that retriggers a build when that build has failed. You may decide what retry number is appropriate for you, depending how often A changes. **Important**: *Uncheck* "Trigger new build with the same revisions".

[image]